# Storybook: React is not defined when upgrading to v18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I recently upgraded `react`, `react-dom` and their corresponding type packages from v16 to v18.

Since doing so, I get the following error on any Storybook story which features a React component:

```
    at react-dom/client (http://127.0.0.1:8080/main.1187308f.iframe.bundle.js:1:486489)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8080/runtime~main.bb9256ec.iframe.bundle.js:1:381)
    at __webpack_require__.t (http://127.0.0.1:8080/runtime~main.bb9256ec.iframe.bundle.js:1:1475)
```

This is a Typescript and Gatsby project.  Here are the relevant dependencies/resolutions from `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
  "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/cli": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/react": "^6.5.15",
  "@storybook/source-loader": "^6.5.15",
},
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10"
}
```

For my `main.js`, I precisely copied the [Gatsby Storybook instructions](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/visual-testing-with-storybook/).

How can I fix this error and get a working storybook with React v18?  Per [this github issue comment](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/18331#issuecomment-1162957861) it should be totally possible with Storybook 6.5+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it works when I remove this from the recommended [Gatsby Config](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/visual-testing-with-storybook/):

```
if (parseInt(React.version) <= 18) {
  config.externals = ["react-dom/client"];
}
```

Perhaps they made an error, and this was supposed to be `<` not `<=`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the old `ReactDOM.render` or upgrade your storybook to 7.beta version to use the new API of React.

Comment: Where would I put ReactDom.render?